# Form Filling Pdf Check box appear in IE is unchecked and in Chrome or firefox it appear as checked ? Using itextSharp in C#

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, pdf, adobe, itext

I am using Itextsharp to form filling of PDF using Asp.Net C#. I have identified the check box value to check it using

```
fields.GetAppearanceStates("Pt1Line2_Unit[0]")
```

The code that I used to check is

```
 fields.SetField("Pt1Line3_male[0]", "Y")
```

I have tried this also

```
fields.SetField("Pt1Line3_male[0]", "Y", "Y")
```

It appear as checked in Chrome and firefox but Issue in IE.  I know IE will use installed PDF software (adobe Reader Xl)
Even in Adobe Reader Xl also same issue. Abobe version is 11.0.09
This issue is with few check boxes only and remaining are getting as expected only.
Can anyone please solve this issue.

Comment: Is the form possibly a hybrid AcroForm and XFA form? The field name and the fact that Chrome and FF render the form somehow seem to point in that direction. Please share the PDF if possible.

Comment: @mkl Thank you.Click on this link and You can download PDF. PDF was hosted in Gdrive .  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9xY_kkPL0sFN3VBVHBQS1FUUFk/view?usp=sharing)
in this PDF  Gender is checked and Apt in 2 line also checked

Comment: Just to be sure, you shared the PDF which has been manipulated using iTextSharp, haven't you? Which iTextSharp version did you use?

Comment: @mkl  Yes it is manipulated PDF only and  iTextSharp version is 4.0.1.0

Comment: Ok, that explains it. iText(Sharp) versions that old do not support XFA forms. Your PDF is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA form document, i.e. it contains the form field definitions both in the AcroForm and in the XFA form format. Thus, in your program iText(Sharp) manipulates only the AcroForm form structure. Many PDF viewers (e.g. those built into Chrome and FF) also only support AcroForm. Thus, they display your change. IE, on the other hand, usually displays PDFs using an Adobe Reader plugin. Adobe Reader does support and even favor XFA forms. Thus, it does **not** display your change.